# Does wasm support reading/writing to USB?

Tags: c, usb, webassembly

I'd like to connect my webpage to a label printer and scanner. I've seen tutorials on how to write USB drivers in C/C++. Since C/C++ can compile to wasm, is it possible for my wasm file in my webpage to read/write data from/to the different devices connected to my computer via USB?

Comment: How about WebUSB API?

Comment: That's Chrome only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, wasm modules cannot communicate to usb devices.

The WebAssembly virtual machine does not have any built in I/O capabilities. To access the browser DOM, read to file system, or communicate via the network, for example - it must do so via its hosting environment. WebAssembly modules can import and export functions, allowing you to create the required bridging code.

Comment: Web Assembly doesn't have any native support for USB access. However, other runtime environments and so on can be run on top of Web Assembly. So, my assumption would be that if say .NET Core running on Web Assembly can access USB, then it would be possible to access USB via Web Assembly. Is that what you mean by importing and exporting functions?